# Power Automate - get values when column headers in Column A

Tags: power-automate

I've been googling away on this, and struggling to find anyone who has faced this issue previously and come up with a way to resolve it. I'm trying to pull the value from B7 which is 14/04/2022.

[image]

Currently I'm getting this back, and the problem is the column header is 12/04/2022 and not [Enter End Date] so I have a consistent header to reference later on in the flow.

```
{
  "@odata.context": "",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.etag": "",
      "ItemInternalId": "",
      "Enter Start Date": "Enter End Date",
      "12/04/2022": " 14/04/2022"
    }
  ]
```

My flow is looking like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd use Office Scripts as it can be tailored and controlled much easier than the built in functions that return data from tables.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-office-scripts-in-excel-9fbe283d-adb8-4f13-a75b-a81c6baf163a

I created a script called **Extract Parameters** with the following code ...

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook)
{
  let worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Parameters");

  return {
    "Enter Start Date": worksheet.getRange("B6").getText(),
    "Enter End Date": worksheet.getRange("B7").getText(),
  };
}
```

... and then invoked that script using the `Run script` action in PowerAutomate.

[image: Run script]

This is the resulting output ...

[image: Result]

From there you can use the output in the remainder of your flow.  Just make sure you format your dates as need be.

You can always enhance the script if need be to do a lot more than it currently does but for the specific nature of what you're dealing with, that's simple and works nicely.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that Skin - much appreciated. Funnily enough I was looking at Office Scripts the past couple of hours. The only issue I think I have from my understanding is that you need to have the script imbedded within the Excel file. You can't create the script from Power Automate? The reason I mention it is multiple spreadsheets in this format will be uploaded for processing?

Comment: No, the script is embedded by user account.  So if you have a single user that does the automation work, that script will be available across any workbook that user has access to.  Make sense?  If you want to give the script to someone else, sharing is coming but for now, they can be found in OneDrive for that user and can be given to another user by copying.

Comment: Oh ok! That sounds promising, I'll see if I can find some documentation that explains how to create them so I can copy/paste your code. Cheers Skin!

Comment: Yeah, that URL I provided in the answer gives you that.

Comment: Sure that - thanks. I think the reason I've got confused is I don't see "Automate" on the ribbon within Excel. I'm guessing the company I work for hasn't enabled it. Looks like I'll have to contact the Systems guys.

Comment: Oh ok, that sucks if so but also, make sure you're on the web version, I assume you are but it's only on the web where it shows us.

Comment: Oh geez my bad - thanks Skin! It appears if I launch it on the web version - thanks for your kind help and bearing with me :)

Comment: No worries, it's all part of the service.  :-)